# Navigation using footstep planner and real NAO

Tags: ros, navigation, robot, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

```
I am using footstep planner through the command line NAO_IP=<ip-address> roslaunch footstep_planner footstep_planner_complete.launch. I am able to create a footstep plan according to the instructions in the ROS tutorial 

Also, when I load a robot model, every change in the pose of arms, legs, head, etc, is reflected in the simulated robot.

My question: to control the robot to automatically follow the path just created, should I implement (using the ROS API) a code to interface with RViz to control the robot? Or is there any easier way to accomplish this navigation task?

Thanks!

Marcelo.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133976/navigation-using-footstep-planner-and-real-nao/) by [borghetti](https://answers.ros.org/users/12471/borghetti/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2014-02-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two options. First, you can take the computed footstep plan and execute it open-look with the Nao. Check out the nodes `nao_walker` and `nao_footsteps`, they will allow you to execute a sequence of footsteps computed by `footstep_planner`. The robot will then not correct for drift however, and likely not reach the goal correctly.

As another option you can have a look at the `footstep_navigation` node in the footstep planner (class FootstepNavigation.cpp). It will interleave execution and localization, correct for small errors and start replanning when the derivation is too large. It requires a working pose estimate in the map frame, such as `humanoid_localization` from range or laser data. You will probably have to understand the code yourself and adjust it to your needs, since I haven't used it for some while.

---

Originally posted by [AHornung](https://answers.ros.org/users/141/ahornung/) with karma: 5904 on 2014-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1